# Node.js clustering is slower than single threaded mode

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

I was just experimenting with clustering in `Node.js`. I wrote a little `fibonacci` example, where I called the function using a clustered server and a non-clustered server as follows.

```
// fib.js

module.exports = function () {
    const store = []
    store[0] = 0
    store[1] = 1

    return function fib(n) {
        if (store[n] === undefined) {
            store[n] = fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)
        }

        return store[n]
    }
}
```

---

```
// non-clustered server

const http = require('http')
const fib = require('./fib.js')

const f = fib()
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200)
    res.end(`From ${process.pid}: ${f(30)}\n`)
}).listen(8000)
```

---

```
// clustered server

const cluster = require('cluster')
const http = require('http')
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length
const fib = require('./fib.js')

const f = fib()
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork()
    }
} else {
    http.createServer((req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(200)
        res.end(`From ${process.pid}: ${f(30)}\n`)
    }).listen(8000)
}
```

Now, I tried benchmarking the performance of these two servers using `artillery`  but the non-clustered server seemed to be faster. How come?

```
// Clustered Server Report

Started phase 0, duration: 1s @ 07:53:24(+0000) 2018-11-23
Report @ 07:53:27(+0000) 2018-11-23
  Scenarios launched:  50
  Scenarios completed: 50
  Requests completed:  2000
  RPS sent: 803.21
  Request latency:
    min: 0.3
    max: 70.5
    median: 20.7
    p95: 38.7
    p99: 45.6
  Codes:
    200: 2000

All virtual users finished
Summary report @ 07:53:27(+0000) 2018-11-23
  Scenarios launched:  50
  Scenarios completed: 50
  Requests completed:  2000
  RPS sent: 796.81
  Request latency:
    min: 0.3
    max: 70.5
    median: 20.7
    p95: 38.7
    p99: 45.6
  Scenario counts:
    0: 50 (100%)
  Codes:
    200: 2000
```

---

```
// Non-clustered Server Report

Started phase 0, duration: 1s @ 07:53:39(+0000) 2018-11-23
Report @ 07:53:41(+0000) 2018-11-23
  Scenarios launched:  50
  Scenarios completed: 50
  Requests completed:  2000
  RPS sent: 806.45
  Request latency:
    min: 0.3
    max: 70.1
    median: 21.4
    p95: 38.3
    p99: 44.6
  Codes:
    200: 2000

All virtual users finished
Summary report @ 07:53:41(+0000) 2018-11-23
  Scenarios launched:  50
  Scenarios completed: 50
  Requests completed:  2000
  RPS sent: 800
  Request latency:
    min: 0.3
    max: 70.1
    median: 21.4
    p95: 38.3
    p99: 44.6
  Scenario counts:
    0: 50 (100%)
  Codes:
    200: 2000
```

Comment: Are you sure that `f(30)` does enough work? Otherwise you won't get benefits from multiple processes, while a cluster itself has an overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The [node cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works) documentation says itself, that the worker distribution tends to be very unbalanced due to operating system scheduler vagaries, which affects performance. Also see [this](https://medium.com/@fermads/node-js-process-load-balancing-comparing-cluster-iptables-and-nginx-6746aaf38272) comparsion between the `cluster` `nginx` and `iptables` load balancer.

AFAIK performance testing tends to be much more complicated if we want to get meaningfull results. Some mainly statistic related questions about your test:

1. **Sample sizing**: Why did you choose this sample size? Are you sure that the results will be the same with different sample sizes? Eg.: AFAIK the main advantage of `clustering` kicks off when the single thread process request handling capability ends.
2. **Testing environment**: How did you run your test? In which environment? The environment was isolated? On how many core? What kind of processors?
3. **Significance**: Why do you think your result represents [significant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance) difference? How did you test the difference between the samples?